# How to delete file from the media folder?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this code that deletes all the files saved in a folder and the files in the database table:

```
def delete(request):
    folder = '../f2candon/andon/static/media/fileupload'
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    delet = Media.objects.all()
    delet.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/mediafile/')
```

But I must place another one where only one file is deleted, whether it is deleted by the id, to delete it from the database I do it this way:

```
def delete_media(request, id):
    delete_file = Media.objects.get(pk=id)
    delete_file.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/mediafile/')
```

Is there a way to delete the same file from the media folder that has just been deleted in the database?
The same files are found in the database and in the folder.

Regards.

Comment: Could you not just overwrite the delete function of the Media objects ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [signal handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) for `post_delete` that takes care of [deleting the files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete) after the object in the database is deleted:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Media)
def delete_associated_files(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Removes the media file from disk after deletion."""
    if instance.file:  # assuming the field name is "file"
        instance.file.delete(save=False)
```